# Excel VBA write formula in sheet1, from specific cells in sheet2, sheet3, to sheet(i) where "i" is the number you choose

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, formula, worksheet

I'm in need of help with my code, and hope someone here have an solution they could share.

I am trying to write formulas in Sheet1 in certain cells with VBA, where the formula shall refer to different Sheets with the same name, except they are numbered in the end like: Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4 all the way to sheet"i" which is user determined by the InputBox function.

I have written the following code, but are struggling to make it write the formulas:

- "='Sheet2'!A1" in cell K3 in Sheet1 for i=2
- "='Sheet3'!A1" in cell P3 in Sheet1 for i=3
- and so on till i=i

My Code looks like this:

```
Sub Enter_formulas()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim xNumber As Integer
    xNumber = InputBox("Choose number of sheets")
    For i = 2 To xNumber
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1 + 5 * i).Formula = "='Sheets(i)'!A1"
    Next i
End Sub
```

So basically I want it to write to certain cells in "Sheet1", depending on the number "i" that is an input from user.
"i" defines both what Sheet your formula shall be taken from, and also the position in Sheet1 where the formula shall be written.

So it is the last part of ".Formula = ...... ??" I need help with, if it is possible to write it like this. (It works with constants, just can't figure out how to do it with "i").

Appreciate every suggestions, and if something is badly explained, please tell me :)

Happy Weekend! :)

Stian aka GingerBoy

Comment: `= "='" & Sheets(i).name & "'!A1"`

Comment: Just make sure that the number the user enters is less than or equal to the number of sheets in the workbook.  If you have 8 sheets and the user enter 43, your code will fail.

Comment: Thanks for informing me, Frank.
My script takes care of this, since it generates "i" amount of sheets aswell.
I only posted the part I was unsure of.
If you are interested in seeing the whole script, i can paste it here.
It's not flawless tho, but does the job I need it for :)

Part1, Part 2 under:

Comment: Part 2:It is made to generate sheets (basicly copying Sheet2 into as many copies I need for doing the same calculation with different parametres) to do calculations (in Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4 to Sheet"i", and transporting those results into a document with pages (Sheet1). For every exstra sheet (i) there will be an extra page on Sheet1 (the document that sums up the calulations done in each Sheet(i+1) (Sheet2, Sheet3 etc).

Let me know if you wanna see it, and I'll translate it from Norwegian to English and post it here. 

Have a nice weekend :)